# EF Core generated migration has database brand annotations. Looking for database brand agnostic migrations

Tags: entity-framework

Digging into auto generated migrations files I see references to specific database brand:

```
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", //<-- here
                 SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn), //<--here
```

I use EF2 core to be able to deploy and run application on several database brands. Also, app has references to several database providers:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" ... />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" ... />
```

Why EF2 is not full agnostic about database brand on migrations files? How can I force automatic migrations to write Annotations for all database brands? May be a good Idea to have several projects, each one for a specific database brand? How should I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on [github issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13333) by [Arthur Vickers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2012410/arthur-vickers):

> Documentation for supporting multiple providers in Migrations is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers). We are not planning to implement full scafolding and management for migrations to multiple providers because the cost is very high while the value is relatively low compared to many other things. Also, sometimes multiple migration sets are appropriate, while sometimes a single migration is appropriate.